# cannot import name 'GenerationMixin' from 'transformers.generation' while running executable file creating using pyinstaller

Tags: python, sentence-transformers

I am trying to create a application which checks for sentence similarity. Exe file got created.
Getting the below error message while executing .exe file after giving required inputs.

code

```py
model = pickle.load(open(r"miniLM.sav", "rb")) 
sentences_embeddings = model.encode(desc_corpus) 
c_matrix = cosine_similarity(sentences_embeddings, sentences_embeddings)
```

Error

```
cannot import name 'GenerationMixin' from 'transformers.generation' (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI198962\transformers\generation\__init__.pyc)
```

I have the latest version of transformers - 4.26.1

requirements.txt

```
absl-py==1.4.0
altgraph==0.17.3
astunparse==1.6.3
cachetools==5.3.0
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==3.0.1
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
filelock==3.9.0
flatbuffers==23.1.21
gast==0.4.0
google-auth==2.16.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.51.1
h5py==3.8.0
huggingface-hub==0.12.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==6.0.0
joblib==1.2.0
keras==2.11.0
libclang==15.0.6.1
Markdown==3.4.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
nltk==3.8.1
numpy==1.24.2
oauthlib==3.2.2
openpyxl==3.1.0
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging==23.0
pandas==1.5.3
pefile==2023.2.7
Pillow==9.4.0
protobuf==3.19.6
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pyinstaller==5.7.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2022.15
PyQt5==5.15.9
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
PyQt5-sip==12.11.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-version==0.0.2
pytz==2022.7.1
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
PyYAML==6.0
regex==2022.10.31
requests==2.28.2
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rsa==4.9
scikit-learn==1.2.1
scipy==1.10.0
sentence-transformers==2.2.2
sentencepiece==0.1.97
six==1.16.0
tensorboard==2.11.2
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
tensorflow==2.11.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.11.0
tensorflow-intel==2.11.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.30.0
termcolor==2.2.0
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
tokenizers==0.13.2
torch==1.13.1
torchvision==0.14.1
tqdm==4.64.1
transformers==4.26.1
typing_extensions==4.4.0
urllib3==1.26.14
Werkzeug==2.2.2
wrapt==1.14.1
zipp==3.13.0
```

spec file

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata

datas = [('Config\\\\favicon.ico', '.'), ('Config\\\\miniLM.sav', '.')]
datas += copy_metadata('tqdm')
datas += copy_metadata('regex')
datas += copy_metadata('requests')
datas += copy_metadata('packaging')
datas += copy_metadata('filelock')
datas += copy_metadata('numpy')
datas += copy_metadata('tokenizers')
datas += copy_metadata('importlib_metadata')
datas += copy_metadata('tensorflow')


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['render_ui.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=datas,
    hiddenimports=['sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._datasets_pair', 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._middle_term_computer', 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._argkmin', 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._base', 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._radius_neighbors', 'sentence_transformers.SentenceTransformer', 'tensorflow'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='App',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon='Config\\favicon.ico'
)
```

Downgraded transformers to - 4.25.1
Issue still persists.
I am not sure what is causing this problem. Can someone please help me out on this?

Comment: Don't show the requirements file: verify that `pip list` shows transformers.

Comment: You're not even showing the actual code that throws the error.

Comment: The documentation [suggest](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.26.1/en/main_classes/text_generation#transformers.GenerationMixin) your import is incorrect.

Comment: I am using sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2 which is saved as (.sav file) for sentence embeddings

Comment: Error is raised from 2 line in below code

`model = pickle.load(open(r"miniLM.sav", "rb"))
sentences_embeddings = model.encode(desc_corpus)
c_matrix = cosine_similarity(sentences_embeddings, sentences_embeddings)`

Comment: pip show transformers       
Name: transformers
Version: 4.26.1

Comment: I am getting this error only while running executable file

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant information; not in comments.

Comment: There's still three lines of code, each of which may have the bad import hidden behind them. Please try and limit to the one line that causes the error.

Comment: Also, the error is still one line. There should at least be a few lines: nearly every Python error starts with `Traceback (most recent call last):`, shows a bunch of lines, then shows the error message at the bottom. All of these lines can be relevant; please include them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code changes were made

```
model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
sentences_embeddings = model.encode(desc_corpus)
c_matrix = cosine_similarity(sentences_embeddings, sentences_embeddings)
```

spec file

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata

datas = [('Config\\\\favicon.ico', '.'), ('Config\\\\miniLM.sav', '.')]
datas += copy_metadata('tqdm')
datas += copy_metadata('regex')
datas += copy_metadata('requests')
datas += copy_metadata('packaging')
datas += copy_metadata('filelock')
datas += copy_metadata('numpy')
datas += copy_metadata('tokenizers')
datas += copy_metadata('importlib_metadata')
datas += copy_metadata('torch')

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['render_ui.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=datas,
    hiddenimports=['sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._datasets_pair', 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._middle_term_computer', 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._argkmin', 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._base', 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._radius_neighbors', 'sentence_transformers.SentenceTransformer', 'transformers', 'torch'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='App',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon='Config\\favicon.ico'
)
```

Used below pip commands

```
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio
pip install -U sentence-transformers
```